# how to stop a function from a button in tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, ffmpeg, subprocess

I am trying to record audio from microphone in python with the help of ffmpeg.

By using this i am able to record voice but how can i stop this function by clicking of a button.

to stop this now i am terminating the IDLE forcefully.

```py
import os
import subprocess
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
os.chdir('C://Users/ravir/desktop/')
def recording_voice():
  global p
  p=subprocess.Popen('ffmpeg -f dshow -i audio="Microphone (2- High Definition Audio Device)" sample.mp3' )

def stop_rec():  # ho to stop this ???
    p.terminate()

rec_btn = Button(text='Start Recording', width=20, command=recording_voice)
rec_btn.pack()

stop_btn = Button(text='Stop Recording', width=20, command=stop_rec)
stop_btn.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Add `global p` in `recording_voice()`, then call `p.terminate()` in `stop_rec()`.  Also you need to change `p = subprocess.call(...)` to `p = subprocess.Popen(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 still not terminating the process it is still running updated the code.

Comment: Try removing `shell=True` in `subprocess.Popen(...)`.

Comment: @acw1668 it is recording but when i play the file its says its is corrupted. and my microphone is also recording the audio from last 45 min and it is not stopping probably due to my previous code.

Comment: The corruption may be caused by not terminating the program gracefully.  It is totally depended on how the program handles SIGTERM or SIGKILL signal.

Comment: @acw1668 i think i have to press q to stop recording in cmd and then terminate the cmd. so how to write 'q' in cmd when i click on `stop_rec()`

Comment: Try adding `stdin=subprocess.PIPE` in `subprocess.Popen(...)`, then call `p.communicate(input=b'q')` before terminating the process.

Comment: @acw1668 is there any way to not show the cmd window

Comment: @acw1668 please answer this (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60599434/how-can-i-merge-my-audio-and-video-file-in-python)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/209531/discussion-between-cb9867-and-acw1668).